# Entity Framework to use dictionary object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary

In Entity Framework, I want to see if I can fill a dictionary vs one of the model. In the past I have always map to model object. But I wanted to use a dictionary object to avoid ambiguous because multiple CLR types errors.

```
var dictionaryFlatFee = new Dictionary<int, decimal?>();
var listOfFees = (from p in db.Pricings
                  select new dictionaryFlatFee
                         {
                              p.Id,
                              p.Price,
                         }).AsEnumerable()
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: `var dictionaryFlatFee = await db.Pricings.ToDictionaryAsync(pricing => pricing.Id, pricing => pricing.Price);`

Comment: I answered earlier, but **you accepted someone else's answer**. It's not fair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to finalize the answer due to some of the comments to make it clearer. All you need to do is to retrieve `db.Pricings` and call `ToDictionary()` method which is part of the `Enumerable` API:

```
var FeesDictionary = db.Pricings.ToDictionary(key=>key.Id, val=>val.Price);
```

`db.Pricings` returns a `DbSet<Pricing>` which implements `IEnumerable<Pricing>` so it makes all `Enumerable` methods available to manage the returned entities. You could still `Select()` prior to casting the return as `Dictionary<int, decimal?>` but it's very unnecessary, so just omit it.

I would also like to refer you to [this Site](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/linq/linq-todictionary-method) and will tremendously improve your knowledge on LINQ.

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` is superfluous here.

Comment: I also think `Select` is a bit unnecessary. But since I didn't test this, I just thought I should post what I know will definitely work. LOL!  Let me change this.

Comment: Fair enough. The `Select` probably unnecessary but it reduces the amount of data retrieved from the database which is why I didn't mention it.

Comment: You were absolutely right at @AluanHaddad, This settles it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Just a correction: `Select` here returns `IQueryable<TResult>` because the source is an `IQueryable<T>`, but `IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: I based my answer from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

You can select data that you need and put in `dictionaryFlatFee` dictionary by **ForEach** like this

```cs
var dictionaryFlatFee = new Dictionary<int, decimal?>();
(from p in db.Pricings
    select new 
    {
        p.Id,
        p.Price,
    })
    .ToList().ForEach(a => dictionaryFlatFee.Add(a.Id, a.Price));
```

Another option is [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
var dictionary = db.Pricings.ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => a.Price);
```